# How to address a continuous series of event occurrences without addressing each of them? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Example code to workaround:

```
BooleanThingy = TheEvent[n] or/and TheEvent[n+1] or/and . . . TheEvent[n+k]
```

Somehow…? E.g.:

```
BooleanThingy = that.function(TheEvent[n], k, or/and)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this could be solved with a `for`-loop:

```
var BooleanThingy = true

for i = 0 to k
    BooleanThingy := BooleanThingy and TheEvent[n+i]
```